# Storing my output scraped from website into an array and printing specific part of it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, html-table, jsoup

I am trying to get the top five highest percentage gains from this website's table and store them into an array. I want to print the top 5 highest percentage gains.
http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnyse-gainer.html

As of right now my code gets all of rows and columns and prints them in the output. I am having trouble getting only the top 5, and storing them into my array.

please help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnyse-gainer.html").get();
    Elements rows = doc.select("tr");
    for(Element row :rows)
    {
        Elements columns = row.select("td");
        String[][] trtd = new String[columns.size()][];
        for (Element column:columns)
        {
            System.out.println(column.text());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Curent output is:

```
SEARCH
Issue(Roll over for charts and headlines)
Price
Chg
% Chg
Volume

1
PHH (PHH)
$10.71
2.19
25.65
10,865,948

2
Chico's Fas (CHS)
10.03
1.35
15.63
4,514,899

3
Veeva Systems Cl A (VEEV)
70.48
8.41
13.55
3,300,989

4
Tutor Perini (TPC)
24.70
2.85
13.04
1,723,950

5
TriNet Group (TNET)
46.93
5.35
12.87
1,089,758

6
Nelnet Cl A (NNI)
57.60
5.99
11.61
121,379

7
Federal Signal (FSS)
21.35
1.74
8.87
272,982

etc......
```

Comment: Are you getting them in this order in every case?

Comment: I am not getting your same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use map as storing data ,name for stock name (as i think) and value for present if data is always like this it will work but i recommend to ask site admin maybe there have a simple api

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-gainnyse-gainer.html").get();
    Elements rows = doc.select("tr");

    Map<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> top5 = new HashMap<>(5);

    int arrayFill = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
        Elements columns = rows.get(i).select("td");
        String[][] trtd = new String[columns.size()][];
        for (Element column : columns) {
            System.out.println(column.text());
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (i > 2 &&i <8&& columns.size() > 4) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(1);
            map.put(columns.get(1).text(), columns.get(4).text());
            top5.put(Integer.parseInt(columns.get(0).text()), map);
        }

    }
    System.out.println("using keySet");
    for (Integer key : top5.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + "=" + top5.get(key));
    }


}
```